# How can i test an angular js web application with selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng, e2e-testing

I'm new in Test Automation. I want to use Selenium in order to test web application done by angular js. Can someone suggest to me how to start with a basic application and do you have an example of an angular js application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below two expected conditions will probably do everything you need to make testing an angular site easy.

This one will be the most used expected condition you will have in your code:

```
public static ExpectedCondition angularHasFinishedProcessing() {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            String hasAngularFinishedScript = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];\n" +
                    "var el = document.querySelector('html');\n" +
                    "if (!window.angular) {\n" +
                    "    callback('false')\n" +
                    "}\n" +
                    "if (angular.getTestability) {\n" +
                    "    angular.getTestability(el).whenStable(function(){callback('true')});\n" +
                    "} else {\n" +
                    "    if (!angular.element(el).injector()) {\n" +
                    "        callback('false')\n" +
                    "    }\n" +
                    "    var browser = angular.element(el).injector().get('$browser');\n" +
                    "    browser.notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(function(){callback('true')});\n" +
                    "}";

            JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
            String isProcessingFinished = javascriptExecutor.executeAsyncScript(hasAngularFinishedScript).toString();

            return Boolean.valueOf(isProcessingFinished);
        }
    };
}
```

It will wait for angular to be in a state where it thinks that the site is ready for automated tests to go ahead (This is pretty much stolen from the protector code base and wrapped in Java).  You will need to have a script timeout set for it to work though:

```
webdriver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Finally if you are using angular animate to move things around on the screen you will want this:

```
public static ExpectedCondition angularAnimationsAreComplete() {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            int animatingElements = driver.findElements(By.className("ng-animate")).size();

            return animatingElements == 0;
        }
    };
}
```

Angular animate adds the class "ng-animate" to all elements it is moving around.  This condition will wait until that class is not longer applied to any elements, or in other words it will wait until all the animations have completed.

Answer (score 1):

For e2e-testing AngularJS applications, there is a *specialized* package called [`Protractor`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/), which itself is a convenient wrapper around `WebDriverJS` - javascript selenium bindings.

A great place to start is the [Tutorial](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial).

Comment: Thank you, but can i use only Selenium to test that ?

Comment: @Emna thanks, well, do you mean just pure `WebDriverJS`?

Comment: yes, i don't have a large idea about that. I have just used Appium for Mobile Automation. 
I want to knwo if it is possible with only selenium to test an angular js web application?
If yes is there any example that i can start with it to understand basic  notions?

Comment: @Emna if you are starting with AngularJS end-to-end testing and you are comfortable with writing your tests in javascript - Protractor is definitely your choice. You can though use any regular selenium language bindings, like `WebDriverJS` or java-selenium, python-selenium etc, but, what makes Protractor unique is that it is always working in sync with Angular, knowing when it's ready, the page loaded and there are no outstanding http requests etc, there are also angular-specific locators, like `by.model` or `by.repeater`. In regular selenium bindings, you would have to have extra waits.

Comment: The problem i'm not familiar with angular js & javascript. But i'm familiar with appium which is not too far from selenium. So that i would rather start with selenium.

Comment: @Emna sure, it's still a webpage and a browser, you can start with regular selenium webdriver and choose a language that you are comfortable with. Just remember that you would use `WebDriverWait` with Expected Conditions quite often. Hope that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102912/discussion-between-emna-and-alecxe).

Answer (score 1):

I've recently found GitHub project called [jProtractor](https://github.com/caarlos0/jProtractor/). It implements its own `NgWebDriver` based on Selenium `WebDriver`. Most important feature I noticed is that most of basic methods wait for finishing AngularJS script before calling the original method.

Note that I haven't tried it myself so I can't tell how well it works, but it is currently in developement and may contain bugs and lack features.

Hope it helps.